# Pyspark transfrom list of array to list of strings

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given a dataframe with a list of arrays

```
Schema 
|-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- quantity: string (nullable = true)

+-------------------------------+
|items                          |
+-------------------------------+
|[[A, 1], [B, 1], [C, 2]]       |
---------------------------------
```

How do i get a string:

```
+-------------------------------+
|items                          |
+-------------------------------+
|A, 1, B, 1, C, 2               |
---------------------------------
```

Tried:

```
df.withColumn('item_str', concat_ws(" ", col("items"))).select("item_str").show(truncate = False)
```

Error:

```
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'concat_ws(' ', `items`)' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires (array<string> or string) type, however, '`items`' is of array<struct<name:string,quantity:string>> type.;;
```

Comment: The error tells you that you must first transform items array into a array<string> and then call concat on it

Comment: how can i convert the sub element (quantity) to string?

Comment: try using `pyspark.sql.functions.flatten`

Comment: @Bitswazsky i tried flatten: `df.withColumn("items_flat",flatten("items")).show(False)` and got error: `The argument should be an array of arrays, but 'items' is of array<struct<name:string,quantity:string>> type.;;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achive that using a combination of [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) and [array_join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_join) build-in functions:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.withColumn("items", expr("array_join(transform(items, \
                                i -> concat_ws(',', i.name, i.quantity)), ',')"))
```

We use transform to iterate among items and transform each of them into a string of `name,quantity`. Then we use array_join to concatenate all the items, returned by transform, seperated by comma.

Answer (score -1):

Explode might be useful here

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(explode("items")).select("col.*")
```